# I want to know if it's possible to keep the background of a pic and remove the text instead

Tags: image, text, background-image, photoshop, coreldraw

i have tried using some photo editors online but to no avail. trying to extract and use a background image for a particular web page without the text from the image

Comment: This question is off-topic, it has nothing to do with programming. Please read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use Photoshop you can try to Content-Aware Fill.